# javafx is there a css equivalent for flowpane's columnHalignment?

Tags: css, javafx, flowpane

I'd like to put this parameter in my css, is it possible?
something like:
    -fx-column-h-alignment: right;
or
    -fx-column-horizonal-alignment: right;
or
    -fx-columnHalignment: right;

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#flowpane) you can use

```
-fx-column-halignment
```

and

```
-fx-row-valignment
```